# Arquivo Persistence.xml não encontra classe da tag provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa, maven

Estou criando um projeto Hibernate JPA + Maven.
Coloquei as declarações necessárias no pom.xml, e o projeto baixou as dependências do hibernate, mas ao configurar a tag provider do arquivo persistence.xml a IDE me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Cannot resolve class 'HibernatePersistence'.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="Teste">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>Teste</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Adicionei, mas o problema persiste

Comment: Adicione [esta dependência](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/3.1.1.RELEASE) no maven.

Comment: Joia, aparentemente deu certo, só que ao invés de ser HibernatePersistense ele importou org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.